# \chapter to visualize only "the number of the chapter" + "the name of the chapter"

Tags: chapters

i need to visualize when i make a new \chapter only the number of the chapter plus the name of the chapter. for example 1. Introduction, with the input \chapter{Introduction} only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can modify `\@makechapterhead` or use a packege to do it for you.  Neither option is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use package `titlesec` (see its documentation). For example (you can change the format),

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{.25em}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter title}
Hello World!

\end{document}
```

(Depending on the class and other settings you are using, it can be better ways to do it: therfore, always include in your questions a MWE)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a KOMA-Script class, either `scrreprt` or `scrbook`, instead of the corresponding standard class. Chapter number + chapter title in one line is the default with this classes (but can be changed using option `chapterprefix`):

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you additionally want a dot after the number, just use option `numbers=withenddot`. And to not use sans-serif fonts, either change the chapter font using `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}` or deactivate the sans-serif fonts for all sectioning levels using `\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}` or deactivate all sans-serif default of KOMA-Script using option `sfdefaults=false`:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=withenddot,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]